# Laravel SQL parameter bindings when using raw sql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following query:

```
$venues = Venue::select(['id', 'name'])
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->orderByRaw("CASE " .
                         "WHEN name like '{$query}%' THEN 0 " . // start with
                         "WHEN name like '% {$query}%' THEN 1 " . // start of a later word
                         "ELSE 3 " .
                         "END"
            )
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

The issue is the above query is vulnerable to SQL injection.
How can I fix this?

Parameter bindings is explained here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

But if I do:

```
$venues = Venue::select(['id', 'name'])
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->orderByRaw("CASE " .
                         "WHEN name like '?%' THEN 0 " . // start with
                         "WHEN name like '% ?%' THEN 1 " . // start of a later word
                         "ELSE 3 " .
                         "END",
                         [
                             $query,
                             $query,
                         ]
            )
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

I get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the percent to the query param, like this:

```
...
->orderByRaw("CASE " .
    "WHEN name like ? THEN 0 " . // start with
    "WHEN name like ? THEN 1 " . // start of a later word
    "ELSE 3 " .
    "END",
    [
        "{$query}%",
        "% {$query}%",
    ]
)
...
```

Comment: I think the binding automatically adds ' '